# move npapi plugin object in webpage from one div to another, why plugin destroy and recreate?[chrome， FireFox]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, media-player, npapi, browser-plugin

I got one plugin and embeded to my webpage page, the plugin is used to play media files(.mp3,mp4,m3u8, etc).my webpage looks like:

```
<div id='div1'>Plugin</div>
<div id='div2'><div id='div2sub'></div></div>
```

Plugin created like

```
<object id='plugin' type='xxxx' width='xxxx' height='xxxx'></object>
```

the problem is: when i move plugin from div1 to  div2sub like:

```
var x = document.getElementById('plugin');
var y = document.getElementById('div2sub');
y.appenChild(x);
```

then I find the result
   IE: the plugin still playing media file, video, audio output,it works fine(ActiveX plugin)
   Chrome and FireFox: No video, audio output,plugin not play media file anymore.(npapi Plugin)

I found the reason is: with IE, the Plugin just moved,not destroy then recreate, with chrome and FireFox,the plugin was destroy then recreated, I have one function to register callback event on pluin, chrome console shows my plugin never received callback event, so media file can't be played.

My question is: Is there anyway I can do just move plugin, and the plugin will not be destroyed and recreated with chrome and FireFox, just works like with IE.

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin really is getting re-created you should [file a bug](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines) - re-parenting shouldn't re-spawn the plugin per the WhatWG [*object element*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-object-element) and [*being rendered*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#being-rendered) sections.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty standard issue with npapi plugins, though; they don't behave reliably in any browser that I know of when you move them around in the DOM. Similar issues occur if you change the parent container to display: none, visibility: hidden, overflow: none, etc.  ActiveX controls are even more fun.

The workaround I use is to put the plugin in a floating absolute positioned div. I put another div on the page where I want the plugin to be, and then whenever it needs to be moved I calculate the absolute position of the positioning div and move the floating div to be over it.  It's a bit of a hack, but it works quite well.

Comment: Yes， while ‘display:None’ used, This problem do occur.

Comment: when I hide a plugin I just set the width=1 and height=1

Comment: Hi, 'This is a pretty standard issue with npapi plugins', Can you show more details about it, for I need to show  more evidence to our customer that they shouldn't use appendChild and dispaly: None and　I'm newbie to npapi plugin,thanks.

Comment: Nope, I have no specific details other than my own experience using and writing plugins (including the FireBreath framework) for the last 4-5 years.

Comment: @user2638168: If you still need details, see e.g. [bug 889614](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=889614) and [bug 90268](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90268) - just two examples i remember in Firefox. I'm sure you could find more in our and Chromiums bugtracker.